# Content doesn't wrap in mobile when using CSS Grid

Tags: html, css

This is best described with a gif I think. Here is what is happening:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UdfjT.jpg

I expect the content to continue wrapping on small screens, but it stops doing so and I get a horizontal scrollbar.

Here is a [codepen of the code](https://codepen.io/Ciwan/pen/KKKPzKX).

And here is the code itself because StackOverflow insists that I must put code here too.

**HTML**

```
<div class="l-grid">
  <header>
    <h1 class="logo"><span class="logo__brand-color">M</span>y Site</h1>
  </header>
  <main>
    <div class="quote">
      <img
        src="https://cdn.mos.cms.futurecdn.net/c7dppKDbG3JXuMfybV5tUX-320-80.jpg"
        alt="albert einstein"
        class="quote__image"
      />
      <p class="quote__body">
        A hundred times every day I remind myself that my inner and outer
        life are based on the labors of other men, living and dead, and that
        I must exert myself in order to give in the same measure as I have
        received and am still receiving.
      </p>
      <h3 class="quote__author">Albert Einstein</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="search">
      <input
        type="text"
        class="search__field"
        placeholder="Search quotes"
      />
    </div>
  </main>
  <footer>
    <ul class="footer-nav">
      <li class="footer-nav__item">
        <a href="#" class="footer-nav__link">About</a>
      </li>
      <li class="footer-nav__item footer-nav__item--separator">&middot;</li>
      <li class="footer-nav__item">
        <a href="#" class="footer-nav__link">Contribute</a>
      </li>
      <li class="footer-nav__item footer-nav__item--separator">&middot;</li>
      <li class="footer-nav__item">
        <a href="#" class="footer-nav__link">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </footer>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
  border: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

:root {
  font-size: 100%;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: #292c37;
}

.l-grid {
  display: grid;
  width: 1100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
  grid-template-columns: auto;
  grid-template-rows: auto 2fr 2fr;
  align-items: flex-end;
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

header {
  padding: 20px 0;
}

.logo {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Satisfy", cursive;
  font-weight: 100;
}

.logo__brand-color {
  color: hsl(355, 78%, 39%, 80%);
}

main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr auto;
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

.quote {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto;
  font-size: 1rem;
  grid-gap: 50px;
}

.quote__image {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 140px;
  height: 140px;
  object-fit: cover;
  border: 2px solid hsl(0, 0%, 0%, 60%);
  border-style: inset;
}

.quote__body {
  font-family: "Lora", serif;
  color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%, 85%);
  line-height: 1.93em;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

.quote__author {
  color: hsl(355, 78%, 39%, 80%);
  grid-column: span 2;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

.search {
  background-color: #363a49;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.search__field {
  background-color: #292c37;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  height: 43px;
  width: 100%;
  color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%, 60%);
  font-family: "Lora", serif;
  padding: 10px;
}

footer {
  font-size: 1rem;
  align-self: start;
}

.footer-nav {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 100px);
  justify-content: center;
  align-self: flex-start;
}

.footer-nav__item,
.footer-nav__link {
  color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%, 50%);
  text-align: center;
}

.footer-nav__link {
  font-size: 1em;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

.footer-nav__item--separator {
  font-size: 3em;
  line-height: 0.5em;
}

@media (max-width: 1100px) {
  body {
    padding: 20px;
  }

  .l-grid {
    width: auto;
  }

  .quote {
    grid-template-columns: auto;
    grid-template-rows: auto auto;
    grid-gap: 10px;
  }

  .quote__image {
    display: none;
  }

  .quote__body {
    grid-column: auto;
  }

  .quote__author {
    grid-column: auto;
  }

  header {
    padding: 0;
  }
}
```

I tried inspecting via the developer tools to see if I had some padding or magin issues, but found none of that. I'm not really sure what else I can try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lower the number in autofilll property, as below
100px wide columns makes minimum 500px total 5 columns , so the responsiveness is not good below 500px OR so,

```
.footer-nav {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 64px);
    justify-content: center;
    align-self: flex-start;
}
```

Comment: Of course! thank you very much. I can't believe I missed that.